# How to write logs in node js

Tags: node.js, express, error-logging

Recently i got a work to write log messages to my node js project.I am not sure about what exactly a log message mean,generally for a function we write 2 cases like below

```
  exports.inserttopic = function (req, res) {
  var topics = new Topics(req.body);console.log(topics)
  topics.save(function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return err;
    }
    if (result) {
      data = { status: true, error_code: 0, result: result, message: 'Inserted successfully' };
    }
    res.json(data);
  });
};
```

From the above code,i put console.log(err) for error case .is this a log message?If not how does log message s different from it?I heared something that log messages should be ride into a file.How can i do it,i surfed in google but i didnt come to end in understanding.I really troubled about it.Can anyone suggest me some help and post some good articles.Thanks.

Comment: Check this: https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-logging-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

A "log message" is only some Text Information which is offered by a program.

The message can be written to different output channels.
E.g. you are using the Console channel which is bound on the running program. This means when the program ends the log message may get lost if you don't save it explicitly (e.g. with a text-editor in a file).

The better way is to log into a so called "log-file".

You can write your own function which writes to a file or you can use some logging-framework.

The benefit on a logging framework is, that it mostly offers you the ability to choose, which output channel you prefer (for example also Database!), how the logging message has to look like (e.g. Date and Time at the beginning of each line) and that it offers you different severities.

Severities can be for example of type:

- Error
- Info
- Debug

The Logging Framework (or your configuration) then decides how to handle the different severities.

- Write the severities in different Logfiles (debug.log, error.log)
- Write only messages over the configured Severity Level (e.g. Level Info skips debug messages)
- ...